# Unwanted float expected to be integer

Tags: ruby, integer, floating-point-precision

I'm trying to solve a problem :

> Your task is to write a simple function that takes a number of meters,
>   and outputs it using metric prefixes.For this exercise we just want
>   units bigger than a meter, from meters up to yottameters, excluding
>   decameters and hectometers.All values passed in will be positive
>   integers
>   Examples

```
meters(51500)
# returns "51.5km"

meters(5000000)
# returns "5Mm"
```

My code:

```
def meters(x)
  map_prefix={ 24=>'Y', 21=> 'Z', 18=> 'E', 15=> 'P', 12=> 'T', 9=>'G', 6=>'M', 3=>'k',0=>'' }
  digits=(x.to_i.to_s.size-1)/3  
  division=x/(10.0**(3*digits))
  "#{division}#{map_prefix[3*digits]}m".sub(/\.0([^\d])/,'\1')
end
```

It doesn't work for `meters(56*10**24) #->expected 56Ym ,instead got 56.000000000004Ym`, but it works for bigger numbers such as `meters(88*10**24) #->88Ym`. The code passes 49 out of 50 tests, can someone help me find the error?

Comment: Two stylistic comments. You don't need to use `return` in this case. In Ruby, the last thing evaluated is implicitly `return`ed. Second, don't do the math (`x/(10.0...`) inside the string. It is ugly and a little hard to follow. There is no reason for you to not break it into different variables and create your string from the different parts.

Comment: What is the answer you are getting, and what is the answer you expect from the failing input?

Comment: @JustinWood Thank you for the style corrections and fast answer, should i fix it in the post? And I also added the expected result and the one i got instead, forgot to add the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are multiplying by `10.0`, yet you only want to deal with integers.

Something like the following is what you want. (I'm also doing a couple style changes).

```
def meters(x)
  digits=(x.to_i.to_s.size-1)/3
  prefix = prefixes[3*digits]
  value = x / (10 ** (3 * digits))
  "#{value}#{prefix}m".sub(/\.0([^\d])/,'\1')
end

def prefixes
  {
    24 => 'Y',
    21 => 'Z',
    18 => 'E',
    15 => 'P',
    12 => 'T',
    9 => 'G',
    6 => 'M',
    3 => 'k',
    0 => ''
  }
end
```

This at least gives the correct solution to the one that is wrong. I'm not going to guarantee it is the correct solution to everything.

I made the hash into its own function here because it seems like it would be static. As well was the other things I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: Some of the results have a floating point, `meters(51500);
// returns "51.5km"`.

Comment: In that case, You would need to write a function that can calculate significant digits.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to hack your code to get it working seems to avoid float-pointing number, like here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def meters(x)
  map_prefix={ 24=>'Y', 21=> 'Z', 18=> 'E', 15=> 'P', 12=> 'T', 9=>'G', 6=>'M', 3=>'k',0$
  map_prefix.default = 'Y'
  digits = [((x.to_s.size-1)/3)*3, 24].min
  division = x.to_s.insert(-digits - 1, '.')
  division.sub!(/0+\z/, '')
  division.sub!(/\.\z/, '')
  "#{division}#{map_prefix[digits]}m"
end

puts meters(51500)
puts meters(5000000)
puts meters(5001)
puts meters(88*10**24)
puts meters(88*10**24 + 1)
puts meters(100)
puts meters(88*10**27)
puts meters(88*10**27 + 1)
```

With results like:

```
 ./ruby.rb
51.5km
5Mm
5.001km
88Ym
88.000000000000000000000001Ym
100m
88000Ym
88000.000000000000000000000001Ym
```

More seriously, you need to avoid strings whatsoever (no conversions to string at all should be made).
You need arbitrary precision, so float is not an option at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Float#round`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Float.html#method-i-round) to round the number to certain digits. For this certain problem, `3` should do fine.

```
"#{division.round(3)}#{map_prefix[3*digits]}m".sub(/\.0([^\d])/,'\1')
#          ^^^^^^^^^
```

---

The reason behind the problem is: `Float` can store integers that's pretty big. However, for integers bigger than a certain limit, `Float` cannot store them **precisely**. For [IEEE-754 double precision] floating point, that limit is 2<sup>53</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW this line will change ruby's duck typing to float. (notice you're introducing **10.0** as a float.)

```
division=x/(10.0**(3*digits))
```

When dealing with large numbers, its best to use the built in [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-precs) class. Much cleaner and less error prone, although this is definitely NOT error proof code.

```
require 'bigdecimal'

def meters(x)
  b = BigDecimal.new(x).split
  "#{b[1]}#{prefix[b[3] - b[1].length]}m"
end

def prefix
  {
    24 =>'Y', 21 => 'Z', 18 => 'E', 15 => 'P',
    12 => 'T', 9 =>'G',  6 =>'M', 3 =>'k',0 =>''
  }
end
```

Comment: But that code fails to one of the examples `meters(51500) #yields 515m`

Answer (score 0):

```
UNITS = " kMGTPEZY"

def meters(x)
  sx     = x.to_s
  pwr    = sx.size - 1
  return sx if pwr < 3
  pfx_sz = (pwr < 24) ? (1 + pwr % 3) : pwr - 23
  sxs    = sx.reverse.to_i.to_s.reverse
  sxs    = sxs.ljust([sxs.size, pfx_sz].max, '0')
  pfx    = sxs[0, pfx_sz]
  pfx    << '.' if (pfx.size < sxs.size)  
  "#{ pfx }#{ sxs[pfx_sz..-1] }#{ UNITS[[pwr/3, 8].min] }"
end

meters 3             #=> "3" 
meters 100           #=> "100" 
meters 4000          #=> "4k" 
meters 5001          #=> "5.001k" 
meters 51500         #=> "51.5k" 
meters 5000000       #=> "5M" 
meters 88*10**24     #=> "88Y" 
meters 88*10**24 + 1 #=> "88.000000000000000000000001Y" 
meters 88*10**27     #=> "88000Y" 
meters 88*10**27 + 1 #=> "88000.000000000000000000000001Y"
```